# How to set even spaces between Strings in a listview/listcell?

Tags: listview, javafx

I was wondering whether there was a way to have an equal space between the data in a row. This is what it currently looks like

However I want Price etc. to be aligned. I read about monospace font as they have the same width however the whitespace seems to not be the same width so it's not working.

Comment: I don't why know you use a ListView for this rather than a TableView. If you want further assistance, provide a [mcve] so that your issue can be reproduced via copy and paste.

Comment: @jewelsea I added the full class and FXML file. I also attempted it with the monospaced font and attached the code and image for it however it's still not working. I've considered switching to TableView however I'd like to see if I can find a way around creating even spacing otherwise I might have to change it.

Comment: Please don't remove the [mre] because your question has been answered—it decreases the value of your question for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

**Recommended: Use a TableView instead**

A TableView is probably a better control for this than a ListView.

It is much easier to use a TableView for tabular data and would also likely provide a better user experience. TableViews are also sortable by clicking on column headers, so you don't need the additional combo box for sorting.  I advise you to study a tutorial on TableView usage and consider replacing your solution with a TableView.

**Tabular Data in a ListView**

Even with a monospaced font, your text won't be aligned. The host names will have different lengths.  Prices, number of reviews and number of nights will have different numbers of digits (and should be right aligned).

With a mono spaced font, each individual character, including spaces, will have a constant width.  But, the number of spaces required in each field will vary.  Each field will have different lengths of data to be displayed, but must fit within a constant field size.

To align data like this in columnar format using strings, you need to calculate a number of additional spaces used to pad each field, then place those padding spaces before or after the data in each field to correctly align the field within the column.

One way to do that is to iterate through all of the data and calculate the max length of a field within the data set, then pad all other strings to match that calculation.

Another approach is to provide a standard width (in characters) for each field, then pad or truncate data to fit this width.  That is the approach taken in this solution.

[image: fitted]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MonoSample extends Application {
    private static final AirbnbListingFormatter formatter = new AirbnbListingFormatter();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<AirbnbListing> listings = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new AirbnbListing("Kim", (byte) 12, (byte) 3, (byte) 7),
                new AirbnbListing("Ren", (byte) 7, (byte) 8, (byte) 14),
                new AirbnbListing("Alona", (byte) 3, (byte) 3, (byte) 2)
        );

        ListView<AirbnbListing> listView = new ListView<>(listings);
        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new AirbnbListCell());
        listView.setPrefSize(700,100);
        listView.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace; -fx-font-weight: bold;");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static class AirbnbListCell extends ListCell<AirbnbListing> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(AirbnbListing listing, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(listing, empty);
            setText(
                    !empty && listing != null
                            ? formatter.asPrettyString(listing)
                            : null
            );
        }
    }

    private record AirbnbListing(String hostName, byte price, byte numReviews, byte minNights) {}

    private static class AirbnbListingFormatter {

        private static final String SEP = "  |  ";

        private static final int STRING_LEN = 10;
        private static final int NUM_LEN = 3;

        public String asPrettyString(AirbnbListing listing) {
            return "Host Name: %s%sPrice: %s%sNumber of Reviews: %s%sMinimum nights: %s".formatted(
                    fitAndPad(listing.hostName(), STRING_LEN), SEP,
                    pad(listing.price(), NUM_LEN), SEP,
                    pad(listing.numReviews(), NUM_LEN), SEP,
                    pad(listing.minNights(), NUM_LEN)
            );
        }

        private String fitAndPad(String s, int n) {
            return String.format(
                    "%-" + n + "s",
                    s.substring(
                            0,
                            Math.min(n, s.length())
                    )
            );
        }

        private String pad(byte d, int n) {
            return String.format(
                    "%" + n + "d",
                    d
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Sorting the tabular data**

You also have a sorting feature, which is a different problem, so I haven't provided code for that here.  To implement the sorting feature, use a [SortedList](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) and set the predicate for the sorted list based on a sorting function selected from the associated combobox.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've used parts of your code and adjusted it to mine and it's working! I'll make sure to look into TableViews to see if it'll be better/easier.

Comment: If the answer is correct, you can mark it correct.